# Sacar texto de la foreign key de un modelo django

Tags: python, django

Tengo un formulario con una serie de respuestas que tienen vinculado una pregunta. 
Necesito sacar en una etiqueta el nombre de la pregunta para que se vea por bloque por cada respuesta. Utilizo un formset para guardar todas esas respuestas. Y en la plantilla está así:

```py
<form action="." method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ seguridad_form.management_form }}
            {% for s in seguridad_form %}
                {{ s.RESP_PRG.PRG_NOM }}
                {% bootstrap_field s.RESP_PRG %}
                {% bootstrap_field s.RESP_RESUL %}
                {% bootstrap_field s.RESP_FORM %}
            {% endfor %}
            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Guardar"/>
        </form>
```

Creía que así {{ s.RESP_PRG.PRG_NOM }} me traía el texto la otra tabla. RESP_PRG es FK a la tabla PRG y PRG_NOM es el nombre de la pregunta.

Gracias

Comment: Hola, sería bueno si pudieses agregar el código de tu formulario y de tu formset

Comment: Te lo dejo todo en un pastebin. En él se puede ver que está puesto así: {{resp.RESP_PRG.value}}, pero me saca lo que es el numero de la fk.
https://pastebin.com/eWeuRhRw